# Docker Registry on-prem setup on Artifactory

Tags: docker, nginx, artifactory

I want to know the process of setting up docker registry on Artifactory On-Prem solution, I fail to install it even after repeated tries.

I have used the official doc for the on-prem but had no luck installing it.

So if there was a one piece document which tells the entire setup it would great.

I tried the steps on Nginx web server with Sub Domain method(with the help of Reverse proxy config generator)

P.S - I want to try this locally in LAN kind environment if not on AWS.

Comment: I've done this using both the subdomain method and port mapping method. I followed the docs provided by JFrog. Can you start sharing your specific issues with nginx and artifactory?

Comment: @Scott Do you know if the new method (Repository Path) also supports https or only http?

Comment: I haven't tried the new method. However the docs indicate that the base URL will be whatever your artifactory is set to. So if you've configured http or https that is what you will use.